# How many ways can the hyperplanes for four linear equations in four variables be oriented, and how many solutions in each case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the case of planes for three linear equations in three variables, there are eight fundamental orientations of the R3 planes, each associated with 0, 1, or infinitely many solutions. I want to extend this to four linear equations in four variables. Ultimately I would like to know a general result for n equations in n variables.

Comment: The word "oriented" is probably very misleading. Maybe you should say *positioned* or *arranged*. You still have zero, one, or infinitely many solutions. Just work it out. To be honest, I don't see what your 8 "fundamental" arrangements were to start with. Perhaps you should edit to make your post a lot more informative.

Comment: My eight arrangements for R3 are: 1) 3 planes intersecting at a point (1 solution); 2) Each plane cuts the other two in a line (no solution); 3) Two parallel planes, the third plane cuts each in a line (no solution); 4) Two coincident planes and the other parallel (no solution); 5) Three parallel planes (no solution); 6) Three planes inersect in one line (infinitely many solutions); 7) Two coincident planes and the other plane intersects them in a line (infinitely many solutions); 8) Three coincident planes (infinitely many solutions). Thanks for the comments.

Comment: This sounds like a big headache to me, but here's a small suggestion. First treat the case that all the hyperplanes pass through the origin (i.e., are linear subspaces). List the possibilities. Then move them off the origin. Maybe you should approach this by considering the echelon form of the matrix $A$ (whose rows are the normal vectors of the hyperplanes) and then the echelon form of the augmented matrix $[A|b]$ (to account for moving them off the origin).

Comment: I can now answer my own question. First, to ask the question more clearly: Every two hyperplanes in an nxn system of linear equations either intersect in an (n-1)-dimensional hyperplane, or are parallel, or are coincident. Given these conditions I wanted to know the possible number of configurations of hyperplanes in an nxn system. I have proven a formula that gives these numbers (for n greater than or equal to 3) which I will share if asked. The formula gives 8 configurations for a 3x3 system, 21 for 4x4, 55 for 5x5, and 144 for 6x6, and will find the number for any further value of n.

Comment: Correction: Each hyperplane in an nxn system of linear equations is (n-1)-dimensional. So when two hyperplanes intersect, they intersect in an (n-2)-dimensional hyperplane.